# Splitting a Character's Body

Tags: modeling

I've gone crazy to find the solution to my problem, but I can't get anything clear. I want to separate my character's body into parts so I can hide them in the Unity project I work on. But some lines appear in the cuts that I have made in the character that are also seen in Unity. I asked Unity about the subject, and one answered me, saying something about what I have to preserve the normal ones before cutting, this way the cuts will not be noticed. Is there this function or similar in blender2.8? Is there any other method?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split a smooth shaded object, the normals are recalculated. Their direction is depending on the vertex before and the one after each vertex. If you take the vertex "after" out of the equasion, the normals at the very edge will be modified. Hence the lighting will be treated differently exactly where the split has occured (which is what you are seeing).

The ppl. in the Unity forums were correct, however I am unaware of a method of splitting an object *directly* and keeping the normals at the split. 
Using multiple materials (can be the same material in multiple slots) does pretty much that, but internally, not visibly. 
So a crude approach could be to hide submeshes in Unity. 
Have not tried this, since most ppl. don't split naked characters, but rather hide the seams, but:
Split your object by material slots (assigning them to the faces in edit mode). 
In Unity use: 
myMesh.GetTriangles(mySubmeshIndex);
to show only the triangles that belong to the body part. 
There might be a better solution, but not one I can think of right now.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, there is a way for this to be done in Blender. I know that the *Data Transfer* modifier in Blender can be used to smooth out the joining between distinct objects, but unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with it to provide you with a full walkthrough of how to use it.

Comment: I have tried to use the Data Transfer modifier, and it worked totally and absolutely perfectly, I attached a video of a boy who explains quite well all the modifiers of Blender and precisely talks about this. 

https://youtu.be/z-SG_DcJF5I?t=160